# How can I template a function to return a vector of floats, ints, or structs?

Tags: c++, function, templates

I'm trying to write a function that will return a vector of a given type. Everything works fine if I'm only using vectors of floats and ints as my return type, but if I try to return a vector of structs I get an error that says float or int can't be converted to the type name of the structure. How can I resolve this issue. I have included an example of what I'm trying to do below. Thanks in advance!

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct test
{
    static const int x = 10;
};
template<class T>
vector<T> doStuff(T input, int IT)
{

    if (IT == 1)
    {
        vector<T> result(10);
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            result[i] = 0.1*i;
        return result;
    }
    else if (IT == 2)
    {
        vector<T> result(10);
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            result[i] = i;
        return result;
    }
    else if (IT == 3)
    {
        test t;
        vector<T> result(10);
        for(int i = 0; i < 10 ;i++)
            result[i] = t;
        return result;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    float input1 = 0.0;
    vector<float> result1 = doStuff(input1, 1);
    int input2 = 0;
    vector<int> result2 = doStuff(input2,2);
    test input3;
    vector<test> result3 = doStuff(input3,3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please include the error you're getting.  What it says is important.

Comment: Here's a hint: templates are a compile time thing. The code in a template has to make sense for the types it is instantiated with. You can't "switch" types with if-else blocks.

Answer (score 3):

What you're missing is that the *entire* function has to compile, even the part inside `if (IT == 1)` that assigns float values into a `vector<T>`. This part is causing your problem.

It looks like you're trying to create some sort of algorithm but I can't infer from your question what precisely you're trying to do to perhaps offer a solution to your real problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have a misunderstanding about how templates work. The template arguments must be known when the function template is called or "instantiated". In your case the template argument `T` is deduced from the first argument of `doStuff`. When the template arguments are known it allows for the generation of a new function. The first call to `doStuff` (`doStuff(input1, 1)`) generates a function like this:

```c++
vector<float> doStuff(float input, int IT);
```

What basically happened is that `T` is replaced with the deduced type (that is, `float`). Can you see where this is going? Since `T` is replaced with `float` the compiler sees invalid code like this:

```c++
test t;
vector<float> result(10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10 ;i++)
    result[i] = t;
return result;
```

You're assigning a `float` variable (`result[i]`) to a `test` data type. These types two are incompatible and it will cause an error.

Using the `IT` parameter to "get an idea" of what type was passed is also incorrect. If your functions have different behavior depending on the type you can either use [overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) or function template specialization. I would recommend overloading.

Comment: This makes sense to me. Is there some other way to go about accomplishing this, or will I have to create a function for each return type?

Comment: @Paulithan If your functions have different behavior depending on the type you can use function overloading (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading). No need for templates.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that by making `IT` also a template parameter and using a helper class to do the core work.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct test
{
    static const int x = 10;
};

template <int IT> struct DoStuffHelper;

template <> struct DoStuffHelper<1>
{
   typedef std::vector<int> ReturnType;
   template <class T>
      static ReturnType get(T input)
      {
         ReturnType result(10);
         for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            result[i] = 0.1*i;
         return result;
      }
};

template <> struct DoStuffHelper<2>
{
   typedef std::vector<float> ReturnType;
   template <class T>
      static ReturnType get(T input)
      {
         ReturnType result(10);
         for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            result[i] = 0.1*i;
         return result;
      }
};

template <> struct DoStuffHelper<3>
{
   typedef std::vector<test> ReturnType;

   template <class T>
      static ReturnType get(T input)
      {
        test t;
        ReturnType result(10);
        for(int i = 0; i < 10 ;i++)
            result[i] = t;
        return result;
      }
};

template <int IT, class T>
typename DoStuffHelper<IT>::ReturnType doStuff(T input)
{
   return DoStuffHelper<IT>::get(input);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    float input1 = 0.0;
    vector<int> result1 = doStuff<1>(input1);
    int input2 = 0;
    vector<float> result2 = doStuff<2>(input2);
    test input3;
    vector<test> result3 = doStuff<3>(input3);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a template function that returns different types based on how it's instantiated is easy.

The real problem is that here you're trying to create a template function that does entirely different things depending on how it's instantiated, and some of the combinations of type and actions you try to take on the type apparently aren't allowed.

If you just want to return the same type as was passed in (or some derivative, such as a vector when passed in a T) you can do that pretty easily though:

```
template <class T>
std::vector<T> make10(T const &val) { 
    std::vector<T> ret;

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        ret.push_back(val);
    return ret;
}
```

Now, you do things like:

```
std::vector<double> x = make10(1.0);
std::vector<int> y = make10(1);

test t;
std::vector<test> z = make10(t);
```

While you *can* create multiple functions with the same name that do different things based on the type (using either overloading or specialization) you should generally avoid doing so. Overloading and specialization *should* be used to implement functions that still basically do the same things, but do them in different ways.

At least in most cases, however, when you're dealing with overloaded functions, you should be able to give exactly the same description of what all of them do. If one is "makes N copies of an input" and another is "makes N copies of an input divided by 10", and a third is "makes n copies of a default-constructed object", then you should normally be looking at three separate functions with three separate names, not overloads or specializations of the same function with the same name.